# Relative Jump Out of Range Error

Tags: assembly, tasm

How can I fix the "relative jump out of range" error without inbetween jumps? Like stretching the jump range? I heard about something called long jump or something like that that uses 32-bit instead of the regular 16.

Comment: Which CPU instruction set are you programming?

Comment: Well, that's not a [tasm] error, it figures out by itself that it needs a long jump.  Use the `jmp long somewhere` on yours.

Comment: There's no command like `jmp long`..

Comment: If using Tasm, can you try adding a `/jJUMPS` switch to the command-line and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: What do you mean? I have this line for example: `jz Change`

Comment: I mean on the command-line, when you invoke Tasm.exe to assemble your source file (not within the source code).

Comment: Seems like `tasm file /jJUMPS` works, but it doesn't seem like a solution. I don't want to be having to add `/jJUMPS` everytime I run the program.

Comment: You're not going to add it when you _run_ the program. It's a flag you add when you _assemble_ the program.

Comment: As of now, I need to write "tasm file /jJUMPS" for it to work. How do I do it so I only write "tasm file"

Comment: There is already a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890249/assembler-labels-with-limited-jump-range/27980945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, I found two useful solutions to resolve the error.
The first and used by me is `TASM.cfg`. In TASM, what you'd want to do is to open the `TASM/BIN` folder, create a file named `TASM.cfg` and enter your commands in there, or as I did: `/jJUMPS`. Then, you only send the command `tasm file` and it should work automatically.

The second solution is `file.cmd`. What you'd want to do is to open the `TASM/BIN` folder, create a file named `file.cmd` (or more preferably like your program name) and write the following lines in there:

```
/jJUMPS
YOUR_ASM_FILENAME (WITHOUT EXTENSION)
```

Then, you send the following command in the command line: `tasm @file.cmd`.

Hopefully it helped most of you that get stuck on it too and don't want to make inbetween jumps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around it is putting the branch target closer to the jump.  If you can do that, it saves code-size vs. letting the assembler use a [rel16 or rel32 JCC](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html).

Comment: Only if you're targeting a real 8086 that doesn't support the rel16 / rel32 encoding for conditional jumps.  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html.  If you can rearrange your code so short jumps (rel8) are sufficient, without introducing any extra instructions, then that's great.  But it's not really a good answer to the question.  At best a comment.

Comment: I searched my error , saw this topic which is not helping me out , then share my solution for those who need it Like i needed .

Comment: Sorry I was too harsh the first time.  You're right, it is one way to solve the problem.  But the way you presented it as an answer made it look worse than it was.  Most SO answer that start out with "I have the same problem" are not answers at all, and are just people posting questions in the wrong place.  So I was already biased against your actual answer by the time I saw that it was an answer and not a question.  Anyway, I cleaned it up for you into something that makes a good SO answer.  Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Thanks peter . I'll considered next time .